# Angular Route Throws 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I don't really see what the issue is here.   My Angular Route is not working correctly.

```
var culturalApp = angular.module('culturalApp', ['ngRoute']);

culturalApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "index.php",
        controller: "culturalController"
    }) 

    .when("/event/:eventId", {
        templateUrl: "event.html",
        controller: "eventController"
    })
}])

culturalApp.controller('eventController', function($scope, $http, 
$routeParams) {
    $scope.eventId = $routeParams.eventId;
    console.log($scope.eventId)
})

culturalApp.controller('culturalController', function($scope, $http,
$location, $anchorScroll) { ...
```

culturalsite.com/event/123 throws a 404 error

Comment: check the path of the event.html

Comment: I changed it to '/event.html', still doesn't work

Comment: @TheHawk what is the file directory structure?

Comment: post the folder path you have

Comment: Everything is in the root except the angular code is in '/js' folder

Comment: does the first route work to index.php? does ../event.html work?

Comment: yes...index.php works

Comment: Now I'm not getting a 404 error, but /event brings up index.php